# Lucee 6.0.0.313-SNAPSHOT Error (java.util.NoSuchElementException)

Tags: java, lucee

> lucee.runtime.exp.NativeException: Pool exhausted

Getting this error every two hours on lucee server.
Message: Pool exhausted

Comment: Have you tried a stable Lucee version, instead of the bleeding edge snapshot versions?

Comment: yes sir even stable version does the same